# Disable package messages when loading via R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES

Tags: r, package, message

Is it possible to disable messages when loading packages via R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES? For example, if I add the line

```
R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=noisy_package
```

to my `.Renviron` whenever I restart R, I get a message printed to screen.

---

In general, it's a bad idea to mess about with `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES` but I have a very specific use case.

Comment: I'd say _fsck it_ and use an `.Rprofile` where you get to use code -- ie `suppressMessages(library(data.table))` and you have the package but no three line advertisement.

Comment: That was my first thought. But that messes about with the search path, i.e. data.table is loaded before the standard packages, e.g. graphics, stats. I suppose I could explicitly load the standard packages as well though...